# asp.net generic comparator for typed list

Tags: asp.net

The formulation below won't work, because "p2.item(X)" is not a valid property or method.

How might I write this so that the comparator field can vary based on the sort key value; that is, use something like "p2.item(X)", maybe in Reflection.

```
 Public Sub SortList( _
    ByRef varList As List(Of GVDisplayRow), _
    ByVal varSortKey As String, ByVal varSortSeq As String)

    varList.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p1.item(varSortKey).CompareTo(p2.item(varSortKey))

End Sub
```

The alternative is to use a Select statement, much less elegant.